# How to apply Guided BackProp in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, backpropagation, tensorflow2.0

I am starting with `Tensorflow 2.0` and trying to implement Guided BackProp to display Saliency Map. I started by computing the loss between `y_pred` and `y_true` of an image, then find gradients of all layers due to this loss.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(tf.cast(image_batch_val, dtype=tf.float32))
    print('`logits` has type {0}'.format(type(logits)))
    xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(tf.one_hot(1-label_batch_val, depth=2), dtype=tf.int32), logits=logits)
    reduced = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    grads = tape.gradient(reduced, model.trainable_variables)
```

However, I don't know what to do with gradients in order to obtain the Guided Propagation.

This is my model. I created it using Keras layers:

```
image_input = Input((input_size, input_size, 3))

conv_0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(image_input)
conv_0_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_0)
conv_0_act = Activation('relu')(conv_0_bn)
conv_0_pool = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv_0_act)

conv_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(conv_0_pool)
conv_1_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_1)
conv_1_act = Activation('relu')(conv_1_bn)
conv_1_pool = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv_1_act)

conv_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(conv_1_pool)
conv_2_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_2)
conv_2_act = Activation('relu')(conv_2_bn)
conv_2_pool = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv_2_act)

conv_3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(conv_2_pool)
conv_3_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_3)
conv_3_act = Activation('relu')(conv_3_bn)

conv_4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(conv_3_act)
conv_4_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_4)
conv_4_act = Activation('relu')(conv_4_bn)
conv_4_pool = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(conv_4_act)

conv_5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(conv_4_pool)
conv_5_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_5)
conv_5_act = Activation('relu')(conv_5_bn)

conv_6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='SAME')(conv_5_act)
conv_6_bn = BatchNormalization()(conv_6)
conv_6_act = Activation('relu')(conv_6_bn)

flat = Flatten()(conv_6_act)

fc_0 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(flat)
fc_0_bn = BatchNormalization()(fc_0)

fc_1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(fc_0_bn)
fc_1_drop = Dropout(0.5)(fc_1)

output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(fc_1_drop)

model = models.Model(inputs=image_input, outputs=output)
```

I am glad to provide more code if needed.

Comment: Could you please detail which gradients you want to obtain, exactly? What is your desired result?

Comment: Thank you @rvinas My final goal is to show how much each region in the input image contribute to the outputs of a CNN, like the result in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you have to change the computation of the gradient through a ReLU, i.e. [image: Guided BackProp Formula]

Here a graphic example from the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6806).[image: Graphical example]

This formula can be implemented with the following code:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("GuidedRelu")
def _GuidedReluGrad(op, grad):
   gate_f = tf.cast(op.outputs[0] > 0, "float32") #for f^l > 0
   gate_R = tf.cast(grad > 0, "float32") #for R^l+1 > 0
   return gate_f * gate_R * grad
```

Now you have to override the original TF implementation of ReLU with:

```
with tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'GuidedRelu'}):
   #put here the code for computing the gradient
```

After computing the gradient, you can visualize the result.
However, one last remark. You compute a visualization for a single class. This means, you take the activation of a choosen neuron and set all the activations of the other neurons to zero for the input of Guided BackProp.

Comment: @Simidi thank you for your answer! I think it should work perfectly in Tensorflow 1. However, as I mentioned in my question, I am trying to implement this in Tensorflow 2 in which 'session and graph are no more used. How could I modify your answer to make it work in tensorflow 2?

Comment: if I see [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#gradient_override_map) correctly, you should be able to use the code in tensorflow 2. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thank you very much! It works,. the tf.get_default_graph() becomes tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph() in TF2.0

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but after receiving the gradients, what else do I need to do to get the final saliency map?

Comment: there are several options. You can use absolute value of the gradient or you can square the gradients. After that you can normalize it and then plot it

Answer (score 6):

I tried `@tf.RegisterGradient` and `gradient_override_map` as @Simdi suggested but it was not effective with `TF2`. I am not sure if I was wrong in any steps but it seems that `Relu` has not been replaced by `GuidedRelu`. I think it is because: "There is no built-in mechanism in TensorFlow 2.0 to override all gradients for a built-in operator within a scope." as answered by `mrry` in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55799378/11524628

I used `@tf.custom_gradient` as `mrry` said and it worked perfectly for me:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def guidedRelu(x):
  def grad(dy):
    return tf.cast(dy>0,"float32") * tf.cast(x>0, "float32") * dy
  return tf.nn.relu(x), grad

model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
gb_model = Model(
    inputs = [model.inputs],
    outputs = [model.get_layer("conv5_block3_out").output]
)
layer_dict = [layer for layer in gb_model.layers[1:] if hasattr(layer,'activation')]
for layer in layer_dict:
  if layer.activation == tf.keras.activations.relu:
    layer.activation = guidedRelu

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  inputs = tf.cast(preprocessed_input, tf.float32)
  tape.watch(inputs)
  outputs = gb_model(inputs)

grads = tape.gradient(outputs,inputs)[0]
```

You can see the implementation with two methods above in this Google Colab Notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17tAC7xx2IJxjK700bdaLatTVeDA02GJn?usp=sharing

- `@tf.custom_gradient` worked
- `@tf.RegisterGradient` didn't work as `relu` not overridden with the registered `GuidedRelu`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your implementation. Worked for me as well!

Comment: Don't you need to add the class label?

Comment: Guided Backpropagation doesn't require the class label. When you want to visualize Guided-GradCAM, yes, we need a class label!

Comment: Okay, I just saw the Captum (pyTorch) and innvestigate (TF 1.0) versions of it GBP and they all require some label, so that's why I asked. Another question that I got is whether there's a different to use the models output and the last conv layer