# How to use gradient_override_map with tf.GradientTape in TF2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'd like to override default gradient calculations in Tensorflow 2.0.

In TF1, each time we run something, we create a Session and a Graph explicitly. Then we can use the `with graph.gradient_override_map({'GradName': 'CustGradName'})` context apply the custom-registered gradient. In TF2, graphs and sessions can be created using the `tf.compat.v1` API, so it's done in the same way as follows

```
# tf 2.0.0 with compatible API

# register a custom gradient
@tf.RegisterGradient('CustZero')
    def _custom_grad(op, grad):
        return tf.zeros_like(op.inputs[0])

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    with sess.graph.as_default() as g:
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor([-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
        with g.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'CustZero'}):
            y = tf.nn.relu(x)
        dy = tf.gradients(y , x)
    print(sess.run(dy)[0])

# output: [0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Now in TF2, `tf.function` and `tf.GradientTape` are recommended and is the default way to get gradients. So I'd like to use TF2 native API to do similar things instead of using `tf.compat.v1`. Any functions decorated with `tf.function` will create an `AutoGraph` once it's called. Different graphs will be created and called for different kind of input signatures. If an `input_signature` is past to `tf.function`, only one graph will be created, and therefore it takes tensors matching the specified input signature only. This is called a **[concrete function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/concrete_function)** in TF2. From the concrete function, we can get access to its associated graph and do gradient override. So I did as follows

```
# tf 2.0.0 with tf.function and tf.GradientTape

# register custom gradient
@tf.RegisterGradient('CustZero')
def _custom_grad(op, grad):
    return tf.zeros_like(op.inputs[0])

# create a concrete function with the specified input signatures
@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32),))
def my_relu(x):
    return tf.nn.relu(x)
my_relu_conc = my_relu.get_concrete_function()
    
x = tf.constant([-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0], dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    with my_relu_conc.graph.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'CustZero'}):
        tape.watch(x)
        y = my_relu_conc(x)
dy = tape.gradient(y, x).numpy()
print(dy)

# output: array([0., 0., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)
```

As we see, if seems that the gradient override map doesn't work somehow in the second method. I checked `my_relu_conc.graph._gradient_override_map` and got `{'Relu': 'CustZero'}`, so the context works as expected. However, the custom gradient is not used.

Does anyone know how to use `gradient_override_map` with `tf.function` and `tf.GradientTape` in a correct manner? Thanks!

Comment: You can see the answer from [mrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574081/mrry) through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55799378/11524628. As being said, "there is no built-in mechanism in TensorFlow 2.0 to override all gradients for a built-in operator within a scope.". You can use `@tf.custom_gradient` instead.